# If a person remains absent in any occasion frequently , can they be termed as 'regularly irregular'?

Tags: sentence-structure

If someone remains absent in any occasion frequently can they be termed as' regularly irregular' ? 
Mainly we use 'irregular' but if I use 'regularly irregular' then it will break any rules?

Answer (score 4):

No rules are broken, except nobody will understand what you are talking about!

Irregular doesn't mean absent. If someone sometimes attends the event, you might say that their attendance is irregular. If they never attend then they are *not* irregular. They are absent.

If a person is frequently absent then just say they are "frequently absent". English is hard enough without using an oxymoron like "regularly irregular"

Answer (score 0):

Certainly this is fine. You are saying that on a regular basis, the person shows irregular patterns. No rules broken there. But this **A. Doesn't make sense without context and B. Doesn't mean the person is regularly absent.**